# Nested "CASE when" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i use a nested form of the 'case' statement in a sql query. i am trying to execute the  following query.

```
SELECT AccessTabF1.Month, AccessTabF1.Year, AccessTabF1.[Entity Number], 
case when [Exp Year]= 2010 + 1
     then 'Expires in 1 to 5 Years'
     else
          case when [Exp Year]>2010 + 5
               then 'Expires After 5 Years'
               else 'No Expiration Year Listed' 
end
from AccessTabF1
```

Comment: You need to close each case with `end`.

Comment: Also just to be clear `CASE` is an expression that returns a single value, not a statement. Calling it a statement is probably what leads to the misconception that it is used for control of flow like it is in other languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case you don't need to nest multiple CASE expressions.

```
SELECT AccessTabF1.Month, AccessTabF1.Year, AccessTabF1.[Entity Number], 
case when [Exp Year] = 2010 + 1 -- why not = 2011 ?
     then 'Expires in 1 to 5 Years' -- this does not match the logic on line above
     when [Exp Year] > 2010 + 5 -- why not > 2015 ?
     then 'Expires After 5 Years'
     else 'No Expiration Year Listed' 
end
from AccessTabF1
```